# Suddenly getting shards failed error for the same query that worked till yesterday

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am getting an error 5 of 50 shards failed error as shown below.
I am not sure how to rectify it. It was working as expected till yesterday.
If the index 'cwl-2023.05.28' is corrrupt, can I simply remove the index?

```
{
  "took": 8056,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 50,
    "successful": 45,
    "skipped": 40,
    "failed": 5,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 1,
        "index": "cwl-2023.05.28",
        "node": "Pgrv2KIYQ7K5-UWjSZnc_A",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [apiVersion] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 198,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [

....
....
....
```

Comment: Can you show the query and the mapping of `apiVersion` ?

Comment: The error has gone. The only change that I did was to remove old indices. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: I did not remove the index 'cwl-2023.05.28'. But the error is gone.

Comment: it might be that someone did set `fielddata=true` on the `apiVersion` field of the `cwl-2023.05.28` index, which would make the error go away.